# Why does my for loop only print the first result?

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a big csv where i query data, my idea is to use as for loop and write all selected columns to one excel. ATM i get the right column headers but only the first value to it, what am i doing wrong?

Here's my Code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('zählerstände.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for v, x, d in zip(combined_csv["Zählerstand Beginn"], combined_csv["Zählerstand Ende"], combined_csv['Tag']):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Zählerstand Beginn': [v], 'Zählerstand Ende': [x], 'Tag': [d]})
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.save()
```

My Result looks like this, but in reality there should be 157 entries and not 1.
[image]

Comment: You are overwriting the `df` variable with every iteration.

Comment: Ok, so that means i have to somehow add them and not overwrite it every time - is there any option for that?

Comment: You are overwriting creation of df, try `df=pd.DataFrame()` before for loop and inside for loop use `df.append()` to append rows then also give `to_excel` function outside after the for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly write the selected columns:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("zählerstände.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    df = combined_csv[["Zählerstand Beginn", "Zählerstand Ende", "Tag"]]
    df.to_excel(writer)
```